# Bluetooth audio suddenly lowered and can barely be heard 19.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10

My Bluetooth headphones volume suddenly lowered to where it can barely be heard. The audio can only barely be heard by overriding the max volume limit and setting it to the max. I have opened alsamixer and ensured all output volumes are at the max levels. I have tried disconnecting and repairing the headphones. I have tried reinstalling alsa and pulse audio.

This is my first question on Ask Ubuntu so please let me know what other information I need to provide.